# Unable to reload with Express + Webpack Dev Middleware + Webpack Hot Middleware

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I've been trying to perform Hot Module Replacement forever with the above setup; with failure. Here's my Webpack Configuration

```js
export default {
    entry: [
        DEVELOPMENT && "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
        PATH.SOURCE
    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
              path: path.join(PATH.ASSETS, "js"),
        publicPath: `http://${getenv("WEB_HOST")}:${getenv("WEB_PORT")}/assets/js`,
          filename: DEVELOPMENT ? "bundle.js" : "bundle.[hash].min.js"
    },
...
    plugins: [
...
        DEVELOPMENT && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
...
    ].filter(Boolean),
```

...and here's my `app.js` runnning an express server

```js
const compiler    = Webpack(WebpackConfig);
app.use(WebpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
           hot: DEVELOPMENT,
    publicPath: WebpackConfig.output.publicPath,
      filename: WebpackConfig.output.filename
}));
app.use(WebpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
```

`App/index.jsx`

```js
if ( module.hot ) {
    import("react-hot-loader").then(({ AppContainer }) => {
        module.hot.accept("containers/App", () => {
            render(App, AppContainer);
        });
    });
}
```

Finally, on file change, HMR updates to browser gives me this on Developer Console.

[image]

I've been trying to figure this out forever with little to no luck.

I'm on Webpack 4!

Answer (score 0):

It seems not related to webpack or plugins, have you ever tried replacing "0.0.0.0" with "localhost"? Or use this chrome plugin -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi